# Build conditional SQL which can highlight a day with different hoursofoperation

Tags: sql, oracle

Suppose we have hierarchical relation among, ID1, ID2 and ID3. For each of ID3, we have 7 days work hours slot viz. Start and End. For most parts start and end time are same for all the days.

```
ID1 -> Multiple ID2
ID2 -> Multiple ID3
ID3 -> Min 7 records
```

I am trying to query and find ID1s which have at least one day with different start and end time.

I tried using group by and distinct on ID3 table and nesting back to ID1 but it does not seems to be an effective approach.

Can i do using joins clubbed with conditional approach?

-Thanks.

Additional Details: There are 3 seperate tables having ID1, ID2 and ID3 as their PKs.

Lets say ID1 is BusinessID, ID2 is LineOfBusiness and ID3 is StoreID. Now each StoreID we have 7 days of store open and close times in ID3Table.

I am looking to find businessID for which 2 LineOfBusiness operate on different timings.

I tried putting distinct on combination of start and end time and grouped the result based on count. I mean less then 7  means some day is different. I took ID back to fine corresponding ID1 for that. This approach uses nested queries.

I am hoping to find  solution based on Join.

Hope this adds more clarity in the question. Thanks!

Comment: Sorry, question doesn't make any sense to me.

Comment: your data structure?  how is "highlight" related to a query?

Comment: `GROUP BY ID3 HAVING MIN(starttime) <> MAX(starttime)`?

Comment: Guessing from your question (you need to be more precise in software development)... your ID1 is primary key in one table and foreign key in another, with a one - many relationship with ID2 which is PK in the second table. Then the same with ID2 - ID3 (ID3 in the third table). Somehow you have "standard" start hour and end hour for each ID3 in the third table. Yes - this is done by joining the three tables, coupled with a conditional on the start hour being different from standard or end hour different from standard.

Comment: Please provide table structures, sample data, expected output, what you've tried and why it didn't work in order to help increase the ability for others on here to help you without having to guess at what you might be trying to do. Some good reading: http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you need only informations in which line of business this situation takes place use `group by` and `having`:

```
select t1.id1, t1.name, t2.id2,
       min(t3.dt1) as dt1_min, min(t3.dt2) as dt2_min, 
       max(t3.dt1) as dt1_max, max(t3.dt2) as dt2_max
  from t1 
    join t2 on t2.id1 = t1.id1
    join t3 on t3.id2 = t2.id2
  group by t1.id1, t1.name, t2.id2
  having min(t3.dt1) <> max(t3.dt1) or min(t3.dt2) <> max(t3.dt2)
  order by t1.id1, t2.id2
```

Output:

```
 ID1 NAME        ID2 DT1_MIN     DT2_MIN     DT1_MAX     DT2_MAX
---- ---------- ---- ----------- ----------- ----------- -----------
   2 BUSINESS2    21 2015-01-25  2015-01-30  2015-02-01  2015-02-17
```

---

If you want details use `min()` and `max()` in [analytic](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e41084/functions004.htm#SQLRF06174) version:

```
select id1, name, id2, id3, dt1, dt2 
  from (
    select t1.id1, t1.name, t2.id2, t3.id3, t3.dt1, t3.dt2,
           min(dt1) over (partition by t1.id1, t2.id2) as dt1_min,
           min(dt2) over (partition by t1.id1, t2.id2) as dt2_min,
           max(dt1) over (partition by t1.id1, t2.id2) as dt1_max,
           max(dt2) over (partition by t1.id1, t2.id2) as dt2_max
      from t1 
        join t2 on t2.id1 = t1.id1
        join t3 on t3.id2 = t2.id2)
  where dt1 <> dt1_min or dt1 <> dt1_max
     or dt2 <> dt2_min or dt2 <> dt2_max
  order by id1, id2, id3
```

Output:

```
 ID1 NAME        ID2  ID3 DT1         DT2
---- ---------- ---- ---- ----------- -----------
   2 BUSINESS2    21  211 2015-01-25  2015-01-30
   2 BUSINESS2    21  212 2015-01-25  2015-01-30
   2 BUSINESS2    21  213 2015-02-01  2015-02-17
```

---

Test data:

```
create table t1 (id1 number(3), name varchar2(10));
insert into t1 values (1, 'BUSINESS1');
insert into t1 values (2, 'BUSINESS2');

create table t2 (id2 number(3), id1 number(3));
insert into t2 values (11, 1);
insert into t2 values (12, 1);
insert into t2 values (21, 2);
insert into t2 values (22, 2);

create table t3 (id3 number(3), id2 number(3), dt1 date, dt2 date);
insert into t3 values (111, 11, date '2015-01-25', date '2015-01-30');
insert into t3 values (112, 11, date '2015-01-25', date '2015-01-30');
insert into t3 values (211, 21, date '2015-01-25', date '2015-01-30');
insert into t3 values (212, 21, date '2015-01-25', date '2015-01-30');
insert into t3 values (213, 21, date '2015-02-01', date '2015-02-17');
```